# Android UI for landing screen after login

Tags: android, user-interface

Is this type of UI possible to make it in Android Studio ?
Any help would be appreciated.
Image URL is given below :

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can design with sufficient design skills and coding expertise.

Comment: @Vipin - Any sample code or reference you can provide ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+ui+design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to do hard work

I added for some example link

[CircularMenuView](https://github.com/amanyadav/CircularMenuView)

```
public class PieChartMenu extends View {
    String TAG = PieChartMenu.class.getSimpleName();
    Paint mPaint, solidLinePaint;
    Paint innerSolidCircle;
    Paint innerSolidStroke;
    Paint pieBackgroundSelected, pieBackgroundNormal;
    RectF rect;
    Rect imageBounds = new Rect();

    private Drawable mCustomImage;

    //partitions will be created using no. of icons.
    int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_account_balance_wallet_black_18dp, R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_18dp,
        R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_18dp,R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_18dp,R.drawable.ic_account_balance_black_18dp, R.drawable.ic_add_alarm_black_18dp,};

    public PieChartMenu(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
    }

    public PieChartMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
    }

    public PieChartMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setColor(0xff4b4642);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);

    innerSolidCircle = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    innerSolidCircle.setColor(0xffdbd380);
    innerSolidCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    pieBackgroundSelected = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    pieBackgroundSelected.setColor(0xff615c56);
    pieBackgroundSelected.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    pieBackgroundNormal = new Paint(pieBackgroundSelected);
    pieBackgroundNormal.setColor(0xff8a8c81);

    innerSolidStroke = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    innerSolidStroke.setColor(0xff433741);
    innerSolidStroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    innerSolidStroke.setStrokeWidth(15);

    solidLinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    solidLinePaint.setColor(0xff292b28);
    solidLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    solidLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

    rect = new RectF();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int center = getWidth() / 2;
    float radius = getWidth() / 3;
    float angle = 360f / icons.length;
    //arc padding so that it can start drawing from start
    float arcPadding = 180f;
    imageBounds.set(center - 110, center - 25, center - 60, center + 25);
    rect.set(getWidth() / 2 - radius, getWidth() / 2 - radius, getWidth() / 2 + radius, getWidth() / 2 + radius);
    //drawing background for selected pie
    canvas.drawArc(rect, arcPadding, angle, true, pieBackgroundSelected);
    //draw background for icon
    for (int i = 1; i < icons.length; i++) {
        canvas.drawArc(rect, angle * i+arcPadding, angle, true, pieBackgroundNormal);
    }
    //draw inner solid circle
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getWidth() / 2, getWidth() / 12, innerSolidCircle);
    //inner solid stroke
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getWidth() / 2, getWidth() / 12, innerSolidStroke);
    //draw solid division lines

    canvas.save();
    for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
        canvas.rotate(angle, getWidth() / 2, getWidth() / 2);
        canvas.drawLine(getWidth() / 2.5f, getWidth() / 2, getWidth() / 6, getWidth() / 2, solidLinePaint);
    }
    canvas.restore();
    //draw the outer circle
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getWidth() / 2, getWidth() / 3, mPaint);


    //draw icons
    for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(angle / 2 + angle * i, center, center);
        canvas.rotate(-angle / 2 - angle * i,imageBounds.centerX(),imageBounds.centerY());
        mCustomImage = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(icons[i]);
        mCustomImage.setBounds(imageBounds);
        mCustomImage.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }


    }
}
```

in xml

```
 <net.andoridsrc.piechartmenu.PieChartMenu
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

[image]

You need to some other example if you want to work more on it some help

like these

- [RadialBarChart](https://github.com/zavenco/RadialBarChart)
- [Android-Wheel-Menu](https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu)

You can search for like your layout these on google

- Radial menu,layout,ui
- Wheel menu,layout,ui
- Circular menu ,layout,ui

Try these and work not find you want exact but you get help with these links....

Comment: Great answer @arjun